# Verilog comparator

Tags: verilog, comparator

I'm newbie to a verilog.

I did a lot of research, and finally wrote this code, but it seems to not work.

Can anyone fix it for me?

```
module comparator();
    reg[3:0] a, b;
    wire[1:0] equal, lower, greater;    

    if (a<b) begin

        equal = 0;
        lower = 1;
        greater = 0;
    end

    else if (a==b) begin
        equal = 1;
        lower = 0;
        greater = 0;
    end

    else begin
        equal = 0;
        lower = 0;
        greater = 1;
    end;

    initial begin
                $monitor($time, 
                         "a=%b, b=%b, greater=%b, equals=%b, lower=%b",
                          a, b, greater, equal, lower);

                a=9; b=10;
                #100 $display ("\n", $time, "\n");
        end
endmodule
```

Comment: I'm not familiar with your technology, but in general, good questions on SE would have the following info:
`What specifically is not working?`
`What have you tried?`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Behavioural procedures must be enclosed within an `always` block, like this:
Also, your module needs inputs and outputs. A more correct version would be like this:

```
module comparator (
    input wire [3:0] a,
    input wire [3:0] b,
    output reg equal,
    output reg lower,
    output reg greater
    );

    always @* begin
      if (a<b) begin
        equal = 0;
        lower = 1;
        greater = 0;
      end
      else if (a==b) begin
        equal = 1;
        lower = 0;
        greater = 0;
      end
      else begin
        equal = 0;
        lower = 0;
        greater = 1;
      end
    end
endmodule
```

I suggest reading some tutorial about behavioral modelling with Verilog, because you missed a lot of points:

- How to correctly define inputs and outputs in a module
- What things can be wires and what things should be regs
- The use of `always @*` to model combinational logic

And most important: how to write a test bench. Test benches are written as module with no inputs and outputs) that instantiates your UUT (unit under test), provides inputs, read outputs and check whether they are valid.

```
module testcomp;
    reg [3:0] a, b;
    wire eq, lw, gr;

    comparator uut (
       .a(a),
       .b(b),
       .equal(eq),
       .lower(lw),
       .greater(gr)
    );

    initial begin
      a = 0;
      repeat (16) begin
        b = 0;
        repeat (16) begin
          #10;
          $display ("TESTING %d and %d yields eq=%d lw=%d gr=%d", a, b, eq, lw, gr);
          if (a==b && eq!=1'b1 && gr!=1'b0 && lw!=1'b0) begin
            $display ("ERROR!");
            $finish;
          end
          if (a>b && eq!=1'b0 && gr!=1'b1 && lw!=1'b0) begin
            $display ("ERROR!");
            $finish;
          end
          if (a<b && eq!=1'b1 && gr!=1'b0 && lw!=1'b1) begin
            $display ("ERROR!");
            $finish;
          end
          b = b + 1;
        end
        a = a + 1;
      end
      $display ("PASSED!");
      $finish;
    end
endmodule
```

You can play with this example at EDAPlayGround using this link:
http://www.edaplayground.com/x/CPq

Comment: Can you show me the way to compare 9 and 10 using this code?

Comment: In the initial block of the test bench, remove all the code between begin and end, and add this: initialize a and b to 9 and 10, wait #10 unit times, and display the values of eq, lw and gr

Answer (score 1):

Without always block:

```
module comparator (
  input wire [3:0] a,
  input wire [3:0] b,
  output reg equal,
  output reg lower,
  output reg greater
);
assign equal = (a===b);
assign lower = (a<b)?1'b1:1'b0;
assign greater = (a>b)1'b1:1'b0;
end
```

Be careful, you need to consider 'X' and 'Z', use "===" instead of "=="